# How to add data for missing values

Tags: python, missing-data

all.

I have a question on how to add missing values to a dataset object.

I'm currently working on crop growth modeling, and employ NASA Power API as a weather dataset.
However, the NASA Power dataset has missing days.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UM818.png)

I used pcse library in order to extract NASA Power dataset.

My question is, how to add the missing day's data.

I tried

wdp(date) = wdp(date-timedelta(days=1))

but it gives me back 'can't assign to function call'

anyhow, it seems that the data for the missing date does not exist in the object and I am not allowed to make it.

Comment: Do you have access to documentation of this NASA Power API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea, but the wrong syntax. In Python, list and dict access uses square brackets (`[]`), see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

To add to that, `pcse`’s [WeatherDataProvider](https://github.com/ajwdewit/pcse/blob/master/pcse/base/weather.py#L337) object does not support this style access. Checking out the code in this link, it appears there is a method you can call named `_store_WeatherDataContainer`, where the leading `_` indicates it is not intended for public use, but that doesn’t mean you can’t :-)

It should look like this:

```py
wdp._store_WeatherDataContainer(wdp(date-timedelta(days=1)), date)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! it worked. Actually, since the second argument has to be the missing date, it went like this:
wdp._store_WeatherDateContainer(wdp(date-timedelta(days=1)), date)

Again, Thank you very much!

Comment: @JinmooLee Glad it worked! Happy to give your first answer on StackOverflow. If it helped you, consider [upvoting the answer and accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).